# Xamarin.iOS - PushNotification when the device is off

Tags: azure, push-notification, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

Hi I would like to know if it is possible getting the push notification the server sent while the device os turned off.

How do I configure the app and the Azure Notification Hubs to know the device did not received the notification at the moment it was sent and show them when it gets on (or online) again?

Is it possible to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Notification hub just tells you a notification has been delivered. There´s no way to get a "received" confirmation if that is what you are looking for. This  has actually nothing to do with Azure, it´s just how Apple Push Notification Service (connected with Azure) works.

Apple Push Notification Service (APN) will retain/cache the last (and only the last) notification sent while the device is off. Once the device is online, APN will try to send the notification again. But there is a time limit after which cached notifications will be lost, and that means your notification may never arrive its destiny.

If you really need to get arrival confirmations (ie: like whatsapp confirmations) you should implement it yourself. That would be another question but here are some hints:

- You include an uid in the notification payload
- You save that uid in your server database, in a table that tracks the "pending notifications".
- Device opens the notification and sends an arrival confirmation to the server, passing the uid as parameter => you delete the "pending notification" record on your database table.

How would you resend the pending/lost notifications?

- Option 1: Implement some kind of a background job that checks (in time periods. ie: once every 5 minutes) what notifications didn´t arrive and resend them until they are correctly confirmed.
- Option 2: when your mobile app starts, send a message to the server telling "hey, I´m online again". Then process and send all the pending notifications specific to that user/device, deleting them from the pending notifications table.